# Create a Blank Spark Dataframe in Scala by taking Schema from JSON or YAML File and then load data from multiple csv files in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have json file like this..

```json
[
{"name":"col_name_1", "type":"string","nullable":true},
{"name":"col_name_2","type":"string","nullable":true}
]
```

I want to create Spark Dataframe in Scala by taking column names from this and assign the datatype to it. I don't want to assign manaully the schema in my code script.

After that i will get csv file like this, if i save that df say..
col_name_1, col_name_2

Now I hve multiple csv files in the folder, and i want to laod the data for those columns from those csv files in this above dataframe, where names of columns are there in above dataframe.
And even i have to assign datatype based on above dataframe.

The csv files may be with or without headers. How will I know if it has headers? and what will be the possible solution in both cases.

What I tried is:

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/folder_path/schema_file.json")
df.show()
```

```
+--------------------+--------+------+
|                name|nullable|  type|
+--------------------+--------+------+
|         col_name_1|    true|string|
|        col_name_2|    true|string|
+--------------------+--------+------+
```

```scala
var df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("mergeSchema", "true").csv("/folder_path/*.csv")
```

this loads data directly from all csv files, assuming that they had headers..

Comment: I know we may do like this.. but this is assigning the col_names directly in your script, i want to take the names of column dynamically and datatype as well from json or yaml file..
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("col_1", StringType, true)
    .add("col_2", StringType, true)
And then create a blank dataframe with this schema nd load tables data for 2 scenarios, if some files have headers or some are missing headers.. both cases